# Determine all irreducible representations of $A_{4}$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, finite-groups, representation-theory

I have to determine all the irreducible representations of the alternating group $A_{4}$ over $\mathbb{C}$. So far I have found three, that are all one-dimensional. I believe there is one more that is three-dimensional, but I'm unsure how to find it so any help would be greatly appreciated! Also I was wondering if there was a way that I could show that these four representations are the only irreducible ones?

Comment: Use the fact that there are as many irreducible representations as conjugacy classes to find out if these four are the only ones. Also use the fact that the sums of the squares of the dimensions of these representations must equal the order of the group. This will give you the dimension you are looking for.

Comment: You could maybe think about decomposing the regular representation, as well (maybe; if it were character theory you could, not sure how hard it is with the actual representations)

Comment: $S_4$ permutes four entities. This gives a natural 4-dimensional representation. It splits into a direct sum of irreducible reps of $S_4$ of dimensions 1 and 3. Can you show that the 3D-component remains irreducible when restricted to $A_4$? Many texts contain a result that when the action of a group on a finite set $X$ is doubly transitive, then the resulting rep of dimension $|X|-1$ is irreducible.

Comment: To show that the 4 representations (the 3 you have and the reduced permutation representation outlined by @JyrkiLahtonen ) are all you either need the criterion about $|G|$ being the sum of the degrees squared, or you need to show that these 4 representations are all which arises in the regular module of the group algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_4$ is an index 2 normal subgroup of $S_4$, which has a natural 3-dimensional irreducible representation: $S_4$ acts on $\Bbb{C}^4$ by permuting the vectors in some fixed choice of basis. This is a 4-dimensional representation, but it is not irreducible -- it has an invariant 1-dimensional subspace consisting of those vectors whose coordinates (with respect to the fixed choice of basis) sum to zero. Call the resulting three-dimensional quotient $\sigma$. By Clifford theory, as $A_4$ is normal in $S_4$ of index 2, either $\sigma$ restricts irreducibly to $A_4$, or $\sigma|_{A_4}=\sigma_1\oplus\sigma_2$, where $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are two irreducible representations of $A_4$ which are conjugate in $S_4$. If representations are conjugate then they are equidimensional, and as 3 is odd this isn't possible. So $\sigma$ restricts irreducibly to $A_4$ and gives your missing representation.

If you aren't familiar with Clifford theory, you can work out the details pretty easily by using character theory.

Comment: What is $\sigma$ explicitly?

Comment: And I'm not sure that the 1-dimensional subspace you have defined is 1-dimensional. Isn't it 3-dimensional? As it is $span\{v_{2}-v_{1},v_{3}-v_{2},v_{4}-v_{3}\}$?

Comment: Er, yes, sorry. The 1-dim subspace is the span of $\{1,1,1,1\}$; the quotient is then isomorphic to the space I mentioned. $\sigma$ is just the natural representation by permutation matrices (matrices with precisely one non-zero entry in each row and column, which is equal to 1). For example, in $S_2$ it sends the transposition $(1,2)$ to $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.